# What Causes PHP To Redirect Header Before Finished With Script?

Tags: php

On my website I use PHP files for all sorts of things, friending people, creating accounts, and more. I will have a PHP file like so:

```
<?php
    /*Does some sort of action to stored data on the server*/
    header('location: mysite.org');
?>
```

The issue is that the it goes to mysite.org **before** the rest of the PHP is actually updated. This causes problems because if a user, for example, posts a message, it won't appear right away, only after 1 or 2 refreshes it will. How could I fix this? I am accessing these PHP files with HTML forms sending a POST request.

Comment: place the header() at the bottom of the script
no output should be there before header()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the headers after a certain 'action', include a conditional statement. For example, if you're sending POST data, you can do:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
  //do stuff here
header();
}
```

Since you are storing data on a database, you can call the header() after successful insertion into the database.

```
if(!$mysql_query){//if it fails
//do nothing
}
else{
header();
}
```